# Grouping records from one table into one

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

Basically, I'm trying to retrieve only 1 record from a table based on catalog_no and packing_list_no. However, the table I'm retrieving the information from has additional details that I don't need but makes the 1 record I need into 3 distinct records.

I tried summing and grouping the info, but I'm still getting 3 records instead of 1.

Any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question and put the query in as text (so it is readable).

Comment: And what's **exactly** the expected result you want?

Comment: Can't tell anything from the image, but at a guess, you are selecting and grouping with more columns than you need?

Comment: Remove all of your non-aggreate columns from the group by clause (ie qty_shipped, qty_picked and weight_shipped)

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed. Also, [Don't post pictures of code...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584)

Comment: @MrMoose thank you for your valuable input, sir. That solved it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GROUP BY groups your result on the columns quantity picked, quantity shipped and weight shipped. A different value in any of those columns will result into a different row.

You can drop the GROUP BY clause all together, if the desirable result is the packing list and catalog no that you have specified. You can use the GROUP BY clause to columns that you do not use sum to group the result set.

```
SELECT catalog_no, sum(qty_picked), sum(qty_shipped), sum(weight_shipped), packing_list_no, bay_no, carrier_code, tracking_no FROM oeorder_shipping
WHERE packing_list_no='CP12618525' AND catalog_no='437656500'
GROUP BY bay_no, carrier_code, tracking_no;
```